# Deconvolution net with dynamic input width&height

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am implementing U-NET (deconv net) using tensorflow.

The problem arises from my input placeholder has None type dimension.
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, None, 1])

Convolution is fine, but the error occurs when deconvolution is carried out.

Below is the part of code where I get an error:

```
output_shape = list(input_shape)
output_shape[1] *= stride
output_shape[2] *= stride
output_shape[3] = output_channels

deconv = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(input_tensor, kernel, output_shape, [1, stride, stride, 1], padding='SAME')
```

I get an error at ' output_shape[1] *= stride ', so I decided not to learn the upsampling filter but use bilinear interpolation by utilizing

```
tf.image.resize_images(dw_h_convs[4], [dw_h_convs[4].get_shape().as_list()[1] * 2, dw_h_convs[4].get_shape().as_list()[2] * 2])
```

but again, I get an error message as follows: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Obviously, it seems None type cannot be multiplied by a constant.

Is there any way that I can circumvent this problem and run deconv net with dynamic image width&height?

Thanks.